ERROR: flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41) Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
I got this error when I ran:
[ERROR: flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' #0
Products.fetchAndSetProducts (package:my_shop/providers/products.dart:60:7) <asynchronous suspension>
I think it must have trouble with the Firebase database.
here are my codes for products.dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:my_shop/providers/product.dart';

class Products with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Product> _items = [];

  final String authToken;
  final String userId;
  Products(this.authToken, this.userId, this._items);

  //var _showFavoritesOnly = false;
  List<Product> get items {
    // if (_showFavoritesOnly) {
    //   return _items.where((prodItem) => prodItem.isFavorite).toList();
    // }
    return [..._items];
  }

  List<Product> get favoriteItems {
    return _items.where((prodItem) => prodItem.isFavorite).toList();
  }

  Product findById(String id) {
    return _items.firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
  }

  Future<void> fetchAndSetProducts([bool filterByUser = false]) async {
    final filterString =
        filterByUser ? 'orderBy="creatorId"&equalTo="userId"' : '';
    var url = Uri.parse(
        'https://flutter-update-ced0c-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/products.json?auth=$authToken&$filterString');
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      if (extractedData == null) {
        return;
      }
      url = Uri.parse(
          'https://flutter-update-ced0c-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/userFavorites/$userId.json?auth=$authToken');
      final favoriteResponse = await http.get(url);
      final favoriteData = json.decode(favoriteResponse.body);

      final List<Product> loadedProducts = [];
      extractedData.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
        loadedProducts.add(Product(
            id: prodId,
            title: prodData['title'],
            description: prodData['description'],
            price: prodData['price'],
            isFavorite:
                favoriteData == null ? false : favoriteData[prodId] ?? false,
            imageUrl: prodData['imageUrl']));
      });
      _items = loadedProducts;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw (error);
    }
  }

  Future<void> addProduct(Product product) async {
    var url = Uri.parse(
        'https://flutter-update-ced0c-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/products.json?auth=$authToken');
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        url,
        body: json.encode({
          'title': product.title,
          'description': product.description,
          'price': product.price,
          'creatorId': userId,
          'imageUrl': product.imageUrl,
        }),
      );

      final newProduct = Product(
          id: json.decode(response.body)['name'],
          title: product.title,
          description: product.description,
          price: product.price,
          imageUrl: product.imageUrl);
      _items.add(newProduct);
      //_items.insert(0,newProduct);
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw (error);
    }
  }

  Future<void> updateProduct(String id, Product newProduct) async {
    final prodcutIndex = _items.indexWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
    if (prodcutIndex >= 0) {
      var url = Uri.parse(
          'https://flutter-update-ced0c-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/products/$id.json?auth=$authToken');
      await http.patch(
        url,
        body: json.encode({
          'title': newProduct.title,
          'description': newProduct.description,
          'price': newProduct.price,
          'imageUrl': newProduct.imageUrl,
        }),
      );
      _items[prodcutIndex] = newProduct;
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      print('...');
    }
  }

  Future<void> deleteProduct(String id) async {
    var url = Uri.parse(
        'https://flutter-update-ced0c-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/products/$id.json?auth=$authToken');
    final existingProductIndex = _items.indexWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
    Product? existingProduct = _items[existingProductIndex];
    _items.removeAt(existingProductIndex);
    notifyListeners();
    final response = await http.delete(url);
    if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
      _items.insert(existingProductIndex, existingProduct);
      notifyListeners();
      throw const HttpException('Could not delete the product!');
    }
    existingProduct = null;
  }
}

here is the product.dart codes:
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Product with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final double price;
  final String imageUrl;
  bool isFavorite;

  Product({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.price,
    required this.imageUrl,
    this.isFavorite = false,
  });

  void _setFavValue(bool newValue) {
    isFavorite = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> toggleFavoritestatus(String token, String userId) async {
    final oldstatus = isFavorite;
    isFavorite = !isFavorite;
    notifyListeners();
    var url = Uri.parse(
        'https://flutter-update-ced0c-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/userFavorites/$userId/$id.json?auth=$token');
    try {
      final response = await http.patch(url,
          body: json.encode(
            {'isFavorite': isFavorite},
          ));
      if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
        _setFavValue(oldstatus);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      _setFavValue(oldstatus);
    }
  }
}

and here is auth.dart codes as given below:
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:my_shop/models/http_exception.dart';

class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  late String _token;
  DateTime? _expiryDate;
  String _userId = '';

  bool get isAuth {
    return token != null;
  }

  String get token {
    if (_expiryDate != null &&
        _expiryDate!.isAfter(DateTime.now()) &&
        _token != null) {
      return _token;
    }
    return '';
  }

  String get userId {
    return _userId;
  }

  Future<void> _authenticate(
      String email, String password, String urlSegment) async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:$urlSegment?key=AIzaSyBZRkTK0i1rj_rvVNit8bxaBKlpBMvkmGg ');
    try {
      final response = await http.post(url,
          body: json.encode({
            'email': email,
            'password': password,
            'returnSecureToken': true,
          }));
      final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      if (responseData['error'] != null) {
        throw HttpException(responseData['error']['message']);
      }
      _token = responseData['idToken'];
      _userId = responseData['localId'];
      _expiryDate = DateTime.now()
          .add(Duration(seconds: int.parse(responseData['expiresIn'])));
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }


I can't fetch products from the server so the screen of my app is just showing a circular progress indicator.

In your product class, only one variable can produce this error and that is the final String id, So, When you are fetching data convert the id toInt() or make it String.

you have added the products to the loadedProducts list with a foreach in the fetchAndSetProducts method in your code.But you have assigned the prodId to the id property. prodId is an interger value. But the id property of your model class is a string value. Another thing is that when you add a product, the id property is not added to thedatabase. I think that is not a good thing.
first create a unique id for a product. You can use flutter uuid package for that.and change your addProduct method like this
Future<void> addProduct(Product product) async {

  var uuid = Uuid();    //initialize uuid
    var url = Uri.parse(
        'https://flutter-update-ced0c-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/products.json?auth=$authToken');
    try {
      var v1 = uuid.v1(); //assign to the variable
      final response = await http.post(
        url,
        body: json.encode({
          'id':v1,  // add product id
          'title': product.title,
          'description': product.description,
          'price': product.price,
          'creatorId': userId,
          'imageUrl': product.imageUrl,
        }),
      );

      final newProduct = Product(
          id: v1, //change this 
          title: product.title,
          description: product.description,
          price: product.price,
          imageUrl: product.imageUrl);
      _items.add(newProduct);
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw (error);
    }
  }

After your fetchAndSetProducts update like this:
extractedData.forEach((prodData) {
    loadedProducts.add(Product(
        id: prodData['id'], //change this
        title: prodData['title'],
        description: prodData['description'],
        price: prodData['price'],
        isFavorite:
            favoriteData == null ? false : favoriteData[prodData['id']] ?? false,
        imageUrl: prodData['imageUrl']));
  });

Do the same for the other methods

the price is defined as double so I use: 'price: double.parse(prodData['price'])' but an error still exists!

the error is [ERROR: flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

add  model class  to your question

it's done. plz check it out

I think error is your productId

I do not think so!

I update my answer check it
